# How to cancel and release resources of task refusing to cancel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have a webservice that performs "long-running" tasks in queue, which sometimes get stuck due to a bug or insufficient validation (too big task). I need these tasks to cancel in a timely manner so the next clients request can start.

I currently timeout + manual cancel these tasks using `CancellationToken`, and my code is littered with `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. Sometimes the code gets stuck in some 3rd party function that has received an unreasonable request, and sometimes it is just a bug in my code that causes cancel to not happen.

I have read a lot about using `BackgroundService, IHostedService`, and tons of articles showing different ways to cancel async non-cancellable tasks, but they seem to just "return" from the task, leaving it running. This is not working for me because a single request can take up to 90% RAM and 50% CPU on my small server, and might never cancel on their own. So these solutions would result in resource starvation very fast.

This article states that you can't cancel non-cancellable tasks. 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/

EDIT to clarify:
My current solution is to respect the `CancellationToken`, which works 99% of times. What fails is a case like this:

```cs
CT.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
// The matrix Auu can become unreasonably large --> This 3rd party function takes minutes
var cholesky = SparseCholesky.Create(Auu, CSparse.ColumnOrdering.MinimumDegreeAtPlusA);

CT.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

And although i try to fix cases like this and throw exceptions before the function call, I can't find them all, and I'd rather have my clients receive an error than having the server stuck for a long time.I have also forked some 3rd party libraries to enhance their support of `CancellationToken`,but again, some will always surprise me. What I need is a failsafe that makes sure the webservice wont get stuck and become unusable.

The system I currently employ looks simplified like this:

```cs
// this code is in a singleton service in an ASP.NET core 3.0 web app
// this one is used to manually cancel from another method if requested
private CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
public async Task Advance(...)
{
   //...
   cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource())

   ComputeActive(); // This is not awaited, which lets the request finnish (what Chris Pratt mentioned in his answer)

}
private async Task ComputeActive()
{
    //...
    // this combined token handles automatic timeout ~90sec
    // but it will not help if the code is stuck in something that doesn't have CancellationTokens
    using (var timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource(Active.ComputeTimeLimit))
    using (var linkedSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutSource.Token, cancelSource.Token))
    {
        try
        {
            // this is the "long-running" task (0.1seconds to 40 seconds usually)
            var file = await Task.Run(() => product.Create(Active.Action, linkedSource.Token), linkedSource.Token);;
        }catch(...)
    }
}
```

What then is the solution for me? `Thread.Abort()`? Or is it better to restart the entire app?

Solution: I solved this problem by following the advice given in the answer to move the task to another process, which i can then `Environment.Exit(0)` when cancellation with `CancellationToken`takes too long. The worker process must then be restarted.

Comment: The solution is to use a CancellationToken and actually respect it - ie check it, and exit or throw when it's signalled. A CT doesn't get stuck. Post your code, it's impossible to help otherwise

Comment: A task isn't a thread. It represents an asynchronous action. When you return, it stops running, period. Nothing is left running. If returning leaves the CPU at 90% it means something else is running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you have a long running task, you first and foremost should get it out of process. That means scheduling it to run via another process. For example, you could create a worker service and remotely queue work via some sort of evented communication pattern, having it pick up tasks from a database table, etc. The important things it to get it out of your web process, so it doesn't affect your app or its thread pool.

A simpler, but not quite as robust solution is to use a hosted service running in the app itself. This at least provides some degree of segregation and doesn't tie up the request, but it's still in the same process, so it's using the same thread pool, memory, etc.

What you *don't* want to do is run the task in the context of the request, and you definitely don't want to do so without awaiting it, which is I think probably what your issue is here. In other words, you're doing something like:

```
Task.Run(x => MyLongRunningMethod());
```

That let's the request continue and finish, but you've spun out a new thread that you no longer have any direct control over. If it *eventually* finishes, it's not that big of a deal, but if it hangs, then you've permanently consumed a thread from the pool, along with any resources that thread is holding on to. The only thing you *can* do at that point is to restart the entire process, because there's no way to get at this thread any longer to kill it.

Cancellation tokens can help, but they aren't magic. They're an indication that cancellation is requested, but everything all the way down the line has to support cancellation. If you're calling out to something that either doesn't support having a cancellation token passed into, doesn't support cancellation in some sub process, or you aren't even passing the token in in the first place, then it's all for naught. The work will continue indefinitely until it either finishes or errors out.

Long and short, don't use `Task.Run` unless you have a means of cancelling the task, it's something that will always complete, or you are actually awaiting it. Even then, you shouldn't use it *ever* in a web app, since in the best case scenario, you're just swapping one thread for another, and in the worst case scenario, you're consuming threads from the pool for long periods of time, reducing your web app's potential throughput.

Move the work out of the request pipeline and ideally move it out of the process entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer. I have updated my post with more information. I think I will move the "compute" part to another server entirely, but the same problem (of a task not finnishing) remains there. Is there really no good way to just "Ctrl+Alt+Delete" a Task/Thread?

Comment: Can you use a CancellationTokenSource to pass down a CancellationToken? I think that should give you the ability to send a cancellation to your task.

Comment: CancellationTokenSource is only needed if you're spinning up cancellation manually in a console app, for example, or you want to coordinate cancellation of a subset of tasks. In a web app, there's a main CancellationTokenSource to handle request cancellation that you can use all the way down. It's exposed on HttpContext.RequestAborted.